# AVFoundation video size on preview layer

Tags: swift, size, avfoundation, scale, video-capture

How do I maintain an 'image size' in the previewLayer similar to that of the camera app on the iPhone?

At the moment my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is presenting the frames from the capture session fitted to the rectangle size of the  of the preview layer. My preview layer dimension are quite small so I’d like to maintain the same sort of scale as the iPhone’s camera app and view whatever portion of the image can be seen within the bounds of the preview layer - effectively leaving same image size as the built in camera app but with a smaller field of view.

I’ve tried setting the preview layer’s contents to .resizeAspectFill but it still just fits the video output to the frame. I’ve also tried to change the videoScaleAndCropFactor and the AVCaptureDevice’s videoZoomFactor with no success.

```
// how I've set up my device:
let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
                                      deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                      mediaType: AVMediaType.video, 
                                      position: .back).devices

// the preview layer
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
self.previewLayer = previewLayer
self.previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, 
                                         width: self.spineView.spine.frame.width, 
                                         height: self.spineView.spine.frame.height)
self.previewLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
self.spineView.spine.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
```

Comment: Have you tried messing with the bounds of the previewView. If you make the bounds bigger than the frame you should be able to get it to display a section of the preview

Comment: That does enlarge the picture but it changes the size of the preview layer though.

Comment: Even though the frame is still small?

Comment: Changing bounds doesn't leave the frame dimensions unaffected.

Comment: Other options are you draw the previewLayer full screen and mask out the content you don't want. Or use AVCaptureDevice.videoZoomFactor to zoom the view in.

Comment: I'll give the mask a go, videoZoomFactor has no effect for some reason.

Comment: Are you using device.lockForConfiguration() and device.unlockForConfiguration() around your setting of videoZoomFactor

Comment: Yeah, tried that. I think the mask might work.

Comment: The mask idea totally does work, thanks